# python dictionary update methods to extend dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

So i am using dictionary within a dictionary and every time I would try to extend the child_dict, which i do using a loop, only the last iteration value persists while the previous ones are over-written

```
  parent_dict = defaultdict(list)
      for getdata from datasource:
            # I generate 'child_dict' here
            parent_dict[parentDict_key] = child_dict
```

I tried to use .update(child_dict) method but it gives me

```
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I also tried to use .append() method but it makes the parent a list of dictionaries. 
Is there any better way to add new child_dict to my parent_dict and just extend it during each iteration?

Comment: _"only the last iteration value persists while the previous ones are over-written"_. That shouldn't happen. [mcve] please.

Comment: So you want items to be dicts but you initialize it `defaultdict(list)` which make every attribute by default `list` (thus the `update` exception). What is `parentDict_key`? I can't see where it's changing in within the for loop.

Comment: please show us how you generate ‘child dict' in each iteration, did you retrieve it from the parent dict first?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want your values to be dictionaries and not lists you should use:

```
parent_dict = defaultdict(dict)
```

instead of:

```
parent_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

and then to generate:

```
parent_dict[parentDict_key][child_dict_key] = child_dict_value
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the reason why could not use the .update() method.